# Create native android activity via command line only (makefile)

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, arm

## Goal

Creating a **native activity** in android:

- via `vim` & `Makefile` only
- no use of `gradle, ant, maven, android.mk` and all that other stuff

## Problem

- I already created a (java-native) android apk via makefile that works well on my *Samsung S7*.
- When I try to run the app, it crashes with "`Unable to load native library`".
- My gut feeling says I haven't compiled/linked the `android_native_app_glue.c --> libandroid_native_app_glue.a` with  `main.cpp --> libnative-activity.so` properly.
- It works fine with *Google's* pre-compiled armeabi-v7a `libnative-activity.so`
- Here is the source code: https://github.com/skanti/Android-Manual-Build-Command-Line/tree/master/native-activity

I create the static app-glue first as:

```
aarch64-linux-android-gcc -march=armv8-a -c android_native_app_glue.c -o native_app_glue.o
aarch64-linux-android-ar rcs libandroid_native_app_glue.a native_app_glue.o
```

Then I compile and link `main.cpp` with:

```
aarch64-linux-android-c++ -march=armv8-a -std=c++11 -fPIC -c main.cpp -o main.o
aarch64-linux-android-c++ -shared -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM -lnative_app_glue main.o -o libnative-activity.a
```

## Error report

```
AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.native_activity, PID: 30897
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.native_activity/android.app.NativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app/com.example.native_activity-1/lib/arm64/libnative-activity.so
```

Comment: You seem to be building libnative-activity.a, not libnative-activity.so.

Comment: what makes you think that? See the flags ```-fpic``` and ```-shared```. I also checked the ```.so``` via ```readelf```. That also seemed fine.

Comment: You're defining the output file of the final command as "-o libnative-activity.a", but if the file shows up OK then I guess it's not that.

Answer (score 0):

> It works fine with Google's pre-compiled armeabi-v7a
>   libnative-activity.so

If this works then the zygote process is 32-bit. If you're not changing anything else then this implies you are trying to load a 64-bit library into a 32-bit process, which won't work.

If you build a 32-bit library does it work correctly? That would at least prove your build is doing the right thing, and it's just a process creation change needed.